# Running Accounts & sync settings

Tags: android

I am currently retrieving the users gmail username using Android's AccountManager class.
My problem is that my app assumes that the user has already added his Google account to his Android phone and I would just like to ask if it is possible to launch the Account & sync settings app in case the user has not actually bound his Google account to his phone?

```
 AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
 Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
 if (accounts.length == 0) // How?
    // run Accounts & sync settings so that the user can add his Google account
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS